# How to make proper SOAP request using PHP SoapClient when we see an example

Tags: php, soap, header, request, call

I want to receive data using method GetCruise
How to do that in php using SoapClient, of course i know all URLs and I've got PartnerName, Password and AgencyCode
especially i need to know how to construct proper header of envelope using SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders

[image]

GetCruise
Call:
Proxy.Availability.GetCruise(“FO11060119”);

Parameters: 
CruiseCode - the cruise code to be returned

Returns: 
a fully described cruise (including itinerary and segments of an itinerary).

Example of soap envelope:
(headers must contain agency data - name paswword etc. i've got it)

```
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.costacrociere.com/WebAffiliation/GetCruise"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
<Agency xmlns="http://schemas.costacrociere.com/WebAffiliation">
<Code>1111</Code>
<Culture />
</Agency>
<Partner xmlns="http://schemas.costacrociere.com/WebAffiliation">
<Name>AAAA</Name>
<Password>XXXX</Password>
</Partner></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<GetCruise xmlns="http://schemas.costacrociere.com/WebAffiliation">
<CruiseCode>FO11060119</CruiseCode>
</GetCruise>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```